# How to adjust frequency of Amazon Route53 Health Check?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have set up a basic failover process within Amazon Route53 where they conduct a health check and if they're unhappy with the results, they reroute requests to a secondary server. According to my access logs, it appears that this check occurs roughly once a second.

According to:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html

It looks like each datacenter and DNS server does a check every 30 seconds. I'm assuming these checks are staggered, round-robin fashion, hence the illusion of a check every second.

Is there a way to adjust this so that we only get one "ping" say every 15 or 30 seconds?

Comment: Are the health checks actually causing a problem?

Comment: At the present time, no but we want to make sure we're not missing something obvious in the setup.

Comment: I probably wouldn't worry about it. The faster a bad node goes out of service, or a good node comes into service, the better.

Answer (score 1):

## You can't.

Below follows the AWS Console and AWS API that you have available. As you can see, there is no way to configure a higher rate and AWS warns you that configuring the standard 30 seconds intervals results in one request for each 2-3 seconds.

However, as noted by [Michael](https://serverfault.com/questions/514721/how-to-adjust-frequency-of-amazon-route53-health-check#comment582465_514721)'s comment, *The faster a bad node goes out of service, or a good node comes into service, the better* as long this do not causes issues.

And if you have any issue to handle one ping request for each 2-3 seconds, your application have much greater problems.

#### AWS Console:

[image: AWS Console]

#### [AWS API:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_CreateHealthCheck.html)

[image: AWS API]